# Use indexes in a 2d array to get values from 1d array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have array of values

```
values = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

Array of indices to the values

```
indices = np.array([[2, 3],
                    [1, 2],
                    [3, 4]])
```

I want to use indices values as index to values and get a result

```
np.array([[3, 2],
          [4, 3],
          [2, 1])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try `values[indices]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
values[indices]
```

```
array([[3, 2],
       [4, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```